# Why was Mother Ginger banished to the Fourth Realm?

Tags: the-nutcracker-and-the-four-realms

In Disney's *The Nutcracker and the Four Realms*, we find Mother Ginger banished to the Fourth Realm.

We come to understand that

> Sugar Plum's manipulations

must have something to do with it, but is it explained somewhere? Perhaps in additional material?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the movie thrice now, and it's never explained (in the movie).

It's also not really explained why people leave the fourth realm in the first place.

However, according to [The Disney Wikia](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Mother%20Ginger),

> she [Ginger] got tangled up with The Regent of the Land of Sweets, The Sugar Plum Fairy, and was **tricked into carrying out her nefarious deeds**. Sugar Plum pinned all of these deeds upon Mother Ginger, convincing Marie to remove her from The Regent's council.

Comment: That is very interesting. That means the Sugar Plum Fairy may have been planning her revolt for much longer. Also, her motivation seemed to be that Marie left them, but isn't true either, then. _Do we know how Marie died in the first place?_

Comment: To be fair, the movie is loosely based on other stories, so there will be differences  I also think the movie certainly lacks in quite a few explanations of things, but it also isn't explained how Marie dies in the movie either.

Comment: Do you think you can find a better source? I don't know how the Disney Wikia is, but in general, wikia aren't the best of sources.